# Is it possible to tell that one of the coin was biased if coins are changed mid experiment?

Tags: probability, law-of-large-numbers

Suppose I have two coins one is baised i.e its probality of head $\ne 0.5$ and another is a fair one with head and tails as equally likely outcome.

Now I begin tossing the baised coin first and note down the results for very large number of experiments(finite), then I switch to the fair one and do the some but this time I do it for even a larger number.

Then I note the total number of heads and total number of tails.

Now my question : **If I perform the experiment with fair coin for a very large number would it be able to hide the fact that a unfair coin was involved?**

Comment: If you “note down the results” for the first coin, then nothing is hidden. If only the total number of heads for all flips from both coins is recorded as the outcome of the experiment, then the more flips of the fair coin, the closer the fraction of heads would be to 1/2. If the number of flips from each coin is noted, that can be accounted for when computing the p value, so I don’t think it’ll effect the hypothesis test. But if the number of flips from each coin is unknown, I don’t think you’ll be able to compute a p value, because you won’t be able to separate out the effect of the 2nd coin.

Comment: @Joe So if I keep on flipping the fair coin for a long time and only make available the total number of heads and tails , I could in principle hide the fact that a unfair coin was involved.  Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, even if the unfair coin had heads on both sides, then if you flip the fair coin enough times, the expected value can be made as close to 0.5 as you want, making it very likely that, for a hypothesis test, the null hypothesis (that the coin is fair) would not be rejected. However, depending on the true $P(heads)$ for the unfair coin, I believe the fraction of flips for the fair coin would need to approach 1 as the the number of total flips got large (approached infinity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, but the ratio of fair coin flips to unfair coin flips (in order to hide that an unfair coin was ever used) is dependent on the unfairness of the biased coin.

Comment: Can we maybe put a number to the number of trials with fair one if we are give the probability of head of unfair one?

Comment: You would need even more information: how many times you flipped the unbiased coin. And what confidence you would like to have that the coin is unbiased